# Shows negative value in reliability test

Tags: regression

How to test reliability in nominal data?
MY dependent and independent variables are both in ordinal data. I have to find out the contribution of independent variables in dependent variables. is it possible? How can i manage the data?
During the reliability testing of the data i have found the negative value of Corn Bach Alpha ? Error shows "*There is errors in data coding* however there is nor errors in data coding how to solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to CV. Since you’re new here, you may want to take our [tour], which has information for new users. Your question is unclear. You are asking about reliability tests for nominal variables, but then say that the dependent and independent variables are ordinal. Following questions are vague or too general ("How can I manage the data?"). Finally, without seeing the data (or a sample), it is hard to guess whether there is really a coding error or not. Please check this link to improve your question: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).